# How to solve issue of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrive' in Virtual Studio Code

Tags: python, import-module

I did pip install pydrive in the command prompt... tried many forms of doing that
pip3 install pydrive, python3 -m pip install PyDrive...

still getting the error when running the following python code in virtual studio code:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()           
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment ? If yes is this virtual environment open in vscode ?

Comment: The latest is PyDrive2  was released july 5, 2023.      py -m pip install PyDrive2